# I would like some assistance to edit my script to output in a textbox rather than pop up

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a script to 'roll a dice' in google slides. It creates a dropdown list in the tool bar and the output shows as a pop up on my screen. However I would now like to output the result in a textbox so multiple users can see the result of the dice. Could anyone please help?

My script is:

```
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('action')
  .addItem('Roll Dice', 'roll2')
  .addItem('Community Chest', 'chestDraw')
  .addItem('Chance', 'chanceDraw')

  .addToUi();
}



function getRndInteger(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}  



function roll2(){
  var math = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math);
  var math2 = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math2);
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
 ui.alert('You rolled a '+math+' and a '+math2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it with the method [`slide.insertTextBox(text)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#inserttextboxtext)

Sample:

```
function roll2(){
  var math = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math);
  var math2 = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math2);
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
  var text = 'You rolled a '+math+' and a '+math2;
  //chose the slide where the textbox shall be pasted
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
  // you can also specify the position with slide.insertTextBox(text, left, top, width, height)
  slide.insertTextBox(text);
}
```